# How I can use variable as parameter in html thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using in my HTML Thymeleaf

```
<h1 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="${atendida}"
data-speed="1000"></h1>
```

but `data-to="${atendida}"` doesn't work. My controller:

```
modelAndView.addObject("atendida", size);
```

How I can use "atendida" in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<h1 class="timer count-title count-number" data-speed="1000" th:attr="data-to=${atendida}"></h1>`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

If you're looking to simply print the value of the object, you can do:

```
<h1 class="timer count-title count-number" th:text="${atendida}"
data-speed="1000">Some Timer</h1>
```

If you have a custom attribute value, then you can do

```
<h1 class="timer count-title count-number" th:attr="data-to=${atendida}"
data-speed="1000">Timer</h1>
```

If you're looking to do both attributes, you can do:

```
<h1 class="timer count-title count-number" th:attr="data-to=${atendida},data-speed=${someSpeed}">Timer</h1>
```

You can read about this in the [Thymeleaf docs under "Setting Attribute Values."](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html)